# Minimal polynomial of $\sqrt2 + \sqrt3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

I'm new to minimal polynomials and I've tried to find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt2 + \sqrt3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{C}$.

I've come up with $x^4-10x^2+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $x-(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

Can someone tell me if this is correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Perfectly correct.

Comment: @Bernard Agree. You could make it answer.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary: the O.P. only asked for checking.

Comment: Checking is also possible [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662080/find-the-minimal-polynomial-of-sqrt2-sqrt3-over-mathbb-q?rq=1) on MSE.

Comment: In general, for distinct primes $p$, $q$, the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$  is $x^4+2x^2(p+q)+(p-q)^2$; $x-(\sqrt{p} +\sqrt{q})$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.